# I need to remove an character between two parenthesis

Tags: sed

As the title suggests, I need to remove an character between two characters along a string.

E.g. I want to remove the semicolon between two parenthesis

<>word (word ; word) word<>

output desidered:

<>(word word)<>

Answer (score 0):

Your description and the desired output do not match!

To remove the semicolon between two brackets you can use

```
sed '/([^)]*/s/;//'
```

**example**

```
echo "<>word (word ; word) word<>" | sed '/([^)]*/s/;//'
```

**output**

```
<>word (word  word) word<>
```

Comment: Solved In this way I can also hook a sentinel character on the ";" side by side with another, in this case the "&", and preserve it many times  <>gsed -e 's/(\(.*\);&\(.*\);&\(.*\))/(\1 \&\ \2 \&\ \3)/g'<>